# Change expiry date of cloudflares email-decode.min.js with htaccess and/or mod_pagespeed

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I am trying to improve my score for for pagespeed.
The following file is abit annoying right now:

https://example.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/d07b1474/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js

this is cloudflares email-decode, I want to set the expiry for it with either htaccess, the virtual host or mod_pagespeed

This is what I have attempted with no luck (very possible my regex is just wrong)

```
# speed up cloudflare #
<FilesMatch "email\\-decode\\.min\\.js$">
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
</FilesMatch>
# end speed up cloudflare #
```

That is in my .htaccess file.
This is the warning pagespeed gives me:

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static
>   resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded
>   resources from local disk rather than over the network.

Answer (score 0):

That file is being served by Cloudflare, not your origin, so not a way to change it. You could disable email obfuscation in the ScrapeShield portion of the Cloudflare admin console if you don't have email addresses on your site.

Comment: It does list from my URL which is why i thought it *might* have been possible